# <Flutter> Show rtf string in a widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, rtf, richtext

I want to show the contents of an rtf file in a Flutter widget.

Flutter does have a RichText class, but It cannot show rtf texts. I have tried looking for a third-party package in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/), but I cannot find any with this functionality.

I would like to load a string like the next one in a widget:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3082{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang10 Hello world!\par
}

EDIT:
Aclaration: The widget should only show the formatted text, 'Hello World!' in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `pubspec.yaml` to have this peace of code (Spacing is important in this file)

```
assets:
    - assets/example.rtf
```

fetch the text

```
class RftWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RftWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RftWidget> createState() => _RftWidgetState();
}

class _RftWidgetState extends State<RftWidget> {
  String? _res;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.loadString("assets/text.rtf").then((value) => setState(() {
          _res = value;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_res ?? "Loading . . .");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the original question because I did not explain myself correctly.